# Want to add an active button using for each for same section

Tags: javascript, html, css, foreach

I want to create a active class in `.dflx` and the active class name will be `kp`
but I try to do it by using for-each so that no matter how many of the same section I have but if I click any one `.dflx` div , the active class will be active.
and I only want the active class `.kp` only see on `.dflx`

and I try this code,

```
 Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dflx")).forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("kp");
  });
});
```

when I click the `.svg` div, the class also active on `.svg` div but I want it only active on `.dflx`

```js
document.querySelector(".lverct").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".lverct").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".cmnt").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".cmnt").classList.toggle("kp");

});
document.querySelector(".Share").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".Share").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".lverct1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".lverct1").classList.toggle("kp");
});
document.querySelector(".cmnt1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".cmnt1").classList.toggle("kp");

});
document.querySelector(".Share1").addEventListener("click", () => {
  document.querySelector(".Share1").classList.toggle("kp");
});
```

```css
.pstfeedbackbtn{
margin:10px 20px;
display:flex;
gap:10px;
}
.dflx{
cursor:pointer;
}
.lverct.kp .svg {
  background: #ea4d4d;
}
.lverct1.kp .svg {
  background: #ea4d4d;
}

.cmnt.kp .svg {
  background: green;
}
.cmnt1.kp .svg {
  background: green;
}
.Share.kp .svg {
background:orange;
}
.Share1.kp .svg {
background:orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
      <div class="dflx lverct">
          <div class="svg">
             <svg
                  width="17"
                  height="15"
                  viewBox="0 0 17 15"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                     >
                          <path
                            d="M14.9437 8.04901L14.9537 8.06001L8.05969 14.954L1.16569 8.06001L1.17569 8.05001C0.374702 7.11676 -0.043947 5.91524 0.00365639 4.68631C0.0512597 3.45738 0.561597 2.29185 1.43237 1.42335C2.30315 0.554848 3.47001 0.0475643 4.69906 0.0031787C5.92812 -0.0412069 7.12853 0.380586 8.05969 1.18401C8.99094 0.381944 10.1908 -0.0387741 11.419 0.00608407C12.6472 0.0509423 13.8132 0.558066 14.6835 1.42593C15.5537 2.29379 16.0641 3.45834 16.1123 4.68644C16.1606 5.91454 15.7432 7.11554 14.9437 8.04901V8.04901ZM2.49069 2.49101C2.17728 2.80441 1.92868 3.17647 1.75907 3.58595C1.58946 3.99542 1.50216 4.4343 1.50216 4.87751C1.50216 5.32073 1.58946 5.7596 1.75907 6.16908C1.92868 6.57855 2.17728 6.95061 2.49069 7.26401L8.05969 12.834L13.6287 7.26501C14.2616 6.63207 14.6172 5.77362 14.6172 4.87851C14.6172 3.9834 14.2616 3.12495 13.6287 2.49201C12.9957 1.85907 12.1373 1.50349 11.2422 1.50349C10.3471 1.50349 9.48862 1.85907 8.85569 2.49201L5.67269 5.67401L4.61269 4.61201L6.98369 2.24001C6.33519 1.72209 5.5186 1.46127 4.68996 1.50738C3.86131 1.5535 3.0787 1.90333 2.49169 2.49001V2.49101H2.49069Z"
                            fill="#191919"
                          />
                        </svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>345</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx cmnt">
                        <div class="svg">
                          <svg
                            width="16"
                            height="15"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 15"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M6.5 0H9.5C10.2879 -1.17411e-08 11.0681 0.155195 11.7961 0.456723C12.5241 0.758251 13.1855 1.20021 13.7426 1.75736C14.2998 2.31451 14.7417 2.97595 15.0433 3.7039C15.3448 4.43185 15.5 5.21207 15.5 6C15.5 6.78793 15.3448 7.56815 15.0433 8.2961C14.7417 9.02405 14.2998 9.68549 13.7426 10.2426C13.1855 10.7998 12.5241 11.2417 11.7961 11.5433C11.0681 11.8448 10.2879 12 9.5 12V14.625C5.75 13.125 0.5 10.875 0.5 6C0.5 4.4087 1.13214 2.88258 2.25736 1.75736C3.38258 0.632141 4.9087 0 6.5 0V0ZM8 10.5H9.5C10.5403 10.4986 11.5479 10.1369 12.3516 9.47636C13.1553 8.81587 13.7054 7.89739 13.9083 6.87711C14.1113 5.85684 13.9545 4.79776 13.4648 3.87999C12.9751 2.96222 12.1825 2.24242 11.222 1.843C10.6761 1.61671 10.091 1.50016 9.5 1.5H6.5C5.30653 1.5 4.16193 1.97411 3.31802 2.81802C2.47411 3.66193 2 4.80653 2 6C2 8.707 3.846 10.475 8 12.36V10.5Z"
                              fill="#191919"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>145</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx Share">
                        <div class="svg" id="bubtn">
                          <svg
                            width="23"
                            height="26"
                            viewBox="0 0 23 26"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M17.4151 16.2858C16.3112 16.2858 15.2966 16.6676 14.4957 17.3061L9.49147 14.1785C9.63966 13.5081 9.63966 12.8135 9.49147 12.1432L14.4957 9.01552C15.2966 9.65404 16.3112 10.0358 17.4151 10.0358C20.0039 10.0358 22.1026 7.93715 22.1026 5.34833C22.1026 2.75951 20.0039 0.660828 17.4151 0.660828C14.8263 0.660828 12.7276 2.75951 12.7276 5.34833C12.7276 5.69784 12.7662 6.03827 12.8387 6.36595L7.83453 9.49359C7.03361 8.85511 6.01901 8.47333 4.9151 8.47333C2.32628 8.47333 0.2276 10.572 0.2276 13.1608C0.2276 15.7496 2.32628 17.8483 4.9151 17.8483C6.01901 17.8483 7.03361 17.4665 7.83453 16.8281L12.8387 19.9557C12.7648 20.2899 12.7275 20.6311 12.7276 20.9733C12.7276 23.5621 14.8263 25.6608 17.4151 25.6608C20.0039 25.6608 22.1026 23.5621 22.1026 20.9733C22.1026 18.3845 20.0039 16.2858 17.4151 16.2858Z"
                              fill="black"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
       <span>share</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
      <div class="dflx lverct lverct1">
          <div class="svg">
             <svg
                  width="17"
                  height="15"
                  viewBox="0 0 17 15"
                  fill="none"
                  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                     >
                          <path
                            d="M14.9437 8.04901L14.9537 8.06001L8.05969 14.954L1.16569 8.06001L1.17569 8.05001C0.374702 7.11676 -0.043947 5.91524 0.00365639 4.68631C0.0512597 3.45738 0.561597 2.29185 1.43237 1.42335C2.30315 0.554848 3.47001 0.0475643 4.69906 0.0031787C5.92812 -0.0412069 7.12853 0.380586 8.05969 1.18401C8.99094 0.381944 10.1908 -0.0387741 11.419 0.00608407C12.6472 0.0509423 13.8132 0.558066 14.6835 1.42593C15.5537 2.29379 16.0641 3.45834 16.1123 4.68644C16.1606 5.91454 15.7432 7.11554 14.9437 8.04901V8.04901ZM2.49069 2.49101C2.17728 2.80441 1.92868 3.17647 1.75907 3.58595C1.58946 3.99542 1.50216 4.4343 1.50216 4.87751C1.50216 5.32073 1.58946 5.7596 1.75907 6.16908C1.92868 6.57855 2.17728 6.95061 2.49069 7.26401L8.05969 12.834L13.6287 7.26501C14.2616 6.63207 14.6172 5.77362 14.6172 4.87851C14.6172 3.9834 14.2616 3.12495 13.6287 2.49201C12.9957 1.85907 12.1373 1.50349 11.2422 1.50349C10.3471 1.50349 9.48862 1.85907 8.85569 2.49201L5.67269 5.67401L4.61269 4.61201L6.98369 2.24001C6.33519 1.72209 5.5186 1.46127 4.68996 1.50738C3.86131 1.5535 3.0787 1.90333 2.49169 2.49001V2.49101H2.49069Z"
                            fill="#191919"
                          />
                        </svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>345</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx cmnt cmnt1">
                        <div class="svg">
                          <svg
                            width="16"
                            height="15"
                            viewBox="0 0 16 15"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M6.5 0H9.5C10.2879 -1.17411e-08 11.0681 0.155195 11.7961 0.456723C12.5241 0.758251 13.1855 1.20021 13.7426 1.75736C14.2998 2.31451 14.7417 2.97595 15.0433 3.7039C15.3448 4.43185 15.5 5.21207 15.5 6C15.5 6.78793 15.3448 7.56815 15.0433 8.2961C14.7417 9.02405 14.2998 9.68549 13.7426 10.2426C13.1855 10.7998 12.5241 11.2417 11.7961 11.5433C11.0681 11.8448 10.2879 12 9.5 12V14.625C5.75 13.125 0.5 10.875 0.5 6C0.5 4.4087 1.13214 2.88258 2.25736 1.75736C3.38258 0.632141 4.9087 0 6.5 0V0ZM8 10.5H9.5C10.5403 10.4986 11.5479 10.1369 12.3516 9.47636C13.1553 8.81587 13.7054 7.89739 13.9083 6.87711C14.1113 5.85684 13.9545 4.79776 13.4648 3.87999C12.9751 2.96222 12.1825 2.24242 11.222 1.843C10.6761 1.61671 10.091 1.50016 9.5 1.5H6.5C5.30653 1.5 4.16193 1.97411 3.31802 2.81802C2.47411 3.66193 2 4.80653 2 6C2 8.707 3.846 10.475 8 12.36V10.5Z"
                              fill="#191919"
                            />
                          </svg>
                        </div>
                        <span>145</span>
                      </div>
                      <div class="dflx Share Share1">
                        <div class="svg" id="bubtn">
                          <svg
                            width="23"
                            height="26"
                            viewBox="0 0 23 26"
                            fill="none"
                            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                          >
                            <path
                              d="M17.4151 16.2858C16.3112 16.2858 15.2966 16.6676 14.4957 17.3061L9.49147 14.1785C9.63966 13.5081 9.63966 12.8135 9.49147 12.1432L14.4957 9.01552C15.2966 9.65404 16.3112 10.0358 17.4151 10.0358C20.0039 10.0358 22.1026 7.93715 22.1026 5.34833C22.1026 2.75951 20.0039 0.660828 17.4151 0.660828C14.8263 0.660828 12.7276 2.75951 12.7276 5.34833C12.7276 5.69784 12.7662 6.03827 12.8387 6.36595L7.83453 9.49359C7.03361 8.85511 6.01901 8.47333 4.9151 8.47333C2.32628 8.47333 0.2276 10.572 0.2276 13.1608C0.2276 15.7496 2.32628 17.8483 4.9151 17.8483C6.01901 17.8483 7.03361 17.4665 7.83453 16.8281L12.8387 19.9557C12.7648 20.2899 12.7275 20.6311 12.7276 20.9733C12.7276 23.5621 14.8263 25.6608 17.4151 25.6608C20.0039 25.6608 22.1026 23.5621 22.1026 20.9733C22.1026 18.3845 20.0039 16.2858 17.4151 16.2858Z"
                              fill="black"
            />
          </svg>
        </div>
       <span>share</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `el.classList.toggle("kp");` instead of `e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("kp");` so that it selects the `.dflx` element instead of anything else other than that, like so:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".dflx")).forEach((el) => {
  el.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    el.classList.toggle("kp");
  });
});
```

```css
.pstfeedbackbtn {
  margin: 10px 20px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.dflx {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.lverct.kp .svg {
  background: #ea4d4d;
}

.lverct1.kp .svg {
  background: #ea4d4d;
}

.cmnt.kp .svg {
  background: green;
}

.cmnt1.kp .svg {
  background: green;
}

.Share.kp .svg {
  background: orange;
}

.Share1.kp .svg {
  background: orange;
}
```

```html
<div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
  <div class="dflx lverct">
    <div class="svg">
      <svg width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 17 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path
                            d="M14.9437 8.04901L14.9537 8.06001L8.05969 14.954L1.16569 8.06001L1.17569 8.05001C0.374702 7.11676 -0.043947 5.91524 0.00365639 4.68631C0.0512597 3.45738 0.561597 2.29185 1.43237 1.42335C2.30315 0.554848 3.47001 0.0475643 4.69906 0.0031787C5.92812 -0.0412069 7.12853 0.380586 8.05969 1.18401C8.99094 0.381944 10.1908 -0.0387741 11.419 0.00608407C12.6472 0.0509423 13.8132 0.558066 14.6835 1.42593C15.5537 2.29379 16.0641 3.45834 16.1123 4.68644C16.1606 5.91454 15.7432 7.11554 14.9437 8.04901V8.04901ZM2.49069 2.49101C2.17728 2.80441 1.92868 3.17647 1.75907 3.58595C1.58946 3.99542 1.50216 4.4343 1.50216 4.87751C1.50216 5.32073 1.58946 5.7596 1.75907 6.16908C1.92868 6.57855 2.17728 6.95061 2.49069 7.26401L8.05969 12.834L13.6287 7.26501C14.2616 6.63207 14.6172 5.77362 14.6172 4.87851C14.6172 3.9834 14.2616 3.12495 13.6287 2.49201C12.9957 1.85907 12.1373 1.50349 11.2422 1.50349C10.3471 1.50349 9.48862 1.85907 8.85569 2.49201L5.67269 5.67401L4.61269 4.61201L6.98369 2.24001C6.33519 1.72209 5.5186 1.46127 4.68996 1.50738C3.86131 1.5535 3.0787 1.90333 2.49169 2.49001V2.49101H2.49069Z"
                            fill="#191919"
                          />
                        </svg>
    </div>
    <span>345</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx cmnt">
    <div class="svg">
      <svg width="16" height="15" viewBox="0 0 16 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                              d="M6.5 0H9.5C10.2879 -1.17411e-08 11.0681 0.155195 11.7961 0.456723C12.5241 0.758251 13.1855 1.20021 13.7426 1.75736C14.2998 2.31451 14.7417 2.97595 15.0433 3.7039C15.3448 4.43185 15.5 5.21207 15.5 6C15.5 6.78793 15.3448 7.56815 15.0433 8.2961C14.7417 9.02405 14.2998 9.68549 13.7426 10.2426C13.1855 10.7998 12.5241 11.2417 11.7961 11.5433C11.0681 11.8448 10.2879 12 9.5 12V14.625C5.75 13.125 0.5 10.875 0.5 6C0.5 4.4087 1.13214 2.88258 2.25736 1.75736C3.38258 0.632141 4.9087 0 6.5 0V0ZM8 10.5H9.5C10.5403 10.4986 11.5479 10.1369 12.3516 9.47636C13.1553 8.81587 13.7054 7.89739 13.9083 6.87711C14.1113 5.85684 13.9545 4.79776 13.4648 3.87999C12.9751 2.96222 12.1825 2.24242 11.222 1.843C10.6761 1.61671 10.091 1.50016 9.5 1.5H6.5C5.30653 1.5 4.16193 1.97411 3.31802 2.81802C2.47411 3.66193 2 4.80653 2 6C2 8.707 3.846 10.475 8 12.36V10.5Z"
                              fill="#191919"
                            />
                          </svg>
    </div>
    <span>145</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx Share">
    <div class="svg" id="bubtn">
      <svg width="23" height="26" viewBox="0 0 23 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                              d="M17.4151 16.2858C16.3112 16.2858 15.2966 16.6676 14.4957 17.3061L9.49147 14.1785C9.63966 13.5081 9.63966 12.8135 9.49147 12.1432L14.4957 9.01552C15.2966 9.65404 16.3112 10.0358 17.4151 10.0358C20.0039 10.0358 22.1026 7.93715 22.1026 5.34833C22.1026 2.75951 20.0039 0.660828 17.4151 0.660828C14.8263 0.660828 12.7276 2.75951 12.7276 5.34833C12.7276 5.69784 12.7662 6.03827 12.8387 6.36595L7.83453 9.49359C7.03361 8.85511 6.01901 8.47333 4.9151 8.47333C2.32628 8.47333 0.2276 10.572 0.2276 13.1608C0.2276 15.7496 2.32628 17.8483 4.9151 17.8483C6.01901 17.8483 7.03361 17.4665 7.83453 16.8281L12.8387 19.9557C12.7648 20.2899 12.7275 20.6311 12.7276 20.9733C12.7276 23.5621 14.8263 25.6608 17.4151 25.6608C20.0039 25.6608 22.1026 23.5621 22.1026 20.9733C22.1026 18.3845 20.0039 16.2858 17.4151 16.2858Z"
                              fill="black"
            />
          </svg>
    </div>
    <span>share</span>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="pstfeedbackbtn">
  <div class="dflx lverct lverct1">
    <div class="svg">
      <svg width="17" height="15" viewBox="0 0 17 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                          <path
                            d="M14.9437 8.04901L14.9537 8.06001L8.05969 14.954L1.16569 8.06001L1.17569 8.05001C0.374702 7.11676 -0.043947 5.91524 0.00365639 4.68631C0.0512597 3.45738 0.561597 2.29185 1.43237 1.42335C2.30315 0.554848 3.47001 0.0475643 4.69906 0.0031787C5.92812 -0.0412069 7.12853 0.380586 8.05969 1.18401C8.99094 0.381944 10.1908 -0.0387741 11.419 0.00608407C12.6472 0.0509423 13.8132 0.558066 14.6835 1.42593C15.5537 2.29379 16.0641 3.45834 16.1123 4.68644C16.1606 5.91454 15.7432 7.11554 14.9437 8.04901V8.04901ZM2.49069 2.49101C2.17728 2.80441 1.92868 3.17647 1.75907 3.58595C1.58946 3.99542 1.50216 4.4343 1.50216 4.87751C1.50216 5.32073 1.58946 5.7596 1.75907 6.16908C1.92868 6.57855 2.17728 6.95061 2.49069 7.26401L8.05969 12.834L13.6287 7.26501C14.2616 6.63207 14.6172 5.77362 14.6172 4.87851C14.6172 3.9834 14.2616 3.12495 13.6287 2.49201C12.9957 1.85907 12.1373 1.50349 11.2422 1.50349C10.3471 1.50349 9.48862 1.85907 8.85569 2.49201L5.67269 5.67401L4.61269 4.61201L6.98369 2.24001C6.33519 1.72209 5.5186 1.46127 4.68996 1.50738C3.86131 1.5535 3.0787 1.90333 2.49169 2.49001V2.49101H2.49069Z"
                            fill="#191919"
                          />
                        </svg>
    </div>
    <span>345</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx cmnt cmnt1">
    <div class="svg">
      <svg width="16" height="15" viewBox="0 0 16 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                              d="M6.5 0H9.5C10.2879 -1.17411e-08 11.0681 0.155195 11.7961 0.456723C12.5241 0.758251 13.1855 1.20021 13.7426 1.75736C14.2998 2.31451 14.7417 2.97595 15.0433 3.7039C15.3448 4.43185 15.5 5.21207 15.5 6C15.5 6.78793 15.3448 7.56815 15.0433 8.2961C14.7417 9.02405 14.2998 9.68549 13.7426 10.2426C13.1855 10.7998 12.5241 11.2417 11.7961 11.5433C11.0681 11.8448 10.2879 12 9.5 12V14.625C5.75 13.125 0.5 10.875 0.5 6C0.5 4.4087 1.13214 2.88258 2.25736 1.75736C3.38258 0.632141 4.9087 0 6.5 0V0ZM8 10.5H9.5C10.5403 10.4986 11.5479 10.1369 12.3516 9.47636C13.1553 8.81587 13.7054 7.89739 13.9083 6.87711C14.1113 5.85684 13.9545 4.79776 13.4648 3.87999C12.9751 2.96222 12.1825 2.24242 11.222 1.843C10.6761 1.61671 10.091 1.50016 9.5 1.5H6.5C5.30653 1.5 4.16193 1.97411 3.31802 2.81802C2.47411 3.66193 2 4.80653 2 6C2 8.707 3.846 10.475 8 12.36V10.5Z"
                              fill="#191919"
                            />
                          </svg>
    </div>
    <span>145</span>
  </div>
  <div class="dflx Share Share1">
    <div class="svg" id="bubtn">
      <svg width="23" height="26" viewBox="0 0 23 26" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path
                              d="M17.4151 16.2858C16.3112 16.2858 15.2966 16.6676 14.4957 17.3061L9.49147 14.1785C9.63966 13.5081 9.63966 12.8135 9.49147 12.1432L14.4957 9.01552C15.2966 9.65404 16.3112 10.0358 17.4151 10.0358C20.0039 10.0358 22.1026 7.93715 22.1026 5.34833C22.1026 2.75951 20.0039 0.660828 17.4151 0.660828C14.8263 0.660828 12.7276 2.75951 12.7276 5.34833C12.7276 5.69784 12.7662 6.03827 12.8387 6.36595L7.83453 9.49359C7.03361 8.85511 6.01901 8.47333 4.9151 8.47333C2.32628 8.47333 0.2276 10.572 0.2276 13.1608C0.2276 15.7496 2.32628 17.8483 4.9151 17.8483C6.01901 17.8483 7.03361 17.4665 7.83453 16.8281L12.8387 19.9557C12.7648 20.2899 12.7275 20.6311 12.7276 20.9733C12.7276 23.5621 14.8263 25.6608 17.4151 25.6608C20.0039 25.6608 22.1026 23.5621 22.1026 20.9733C22.1026 18.3845 20.0039 16.2858 17.4151 16.2858Z"
                              fill="black"
            />
          </svg>
    </div>
    <span>share</span>
  </div>
</div>
```